# Regex - At least one occurence of 'F' in a 14 character string but not at 7th position

Tags: regex

I have to check many strings which are 14 characters long.
There should be at least one occurrence of 'F' in a 14 character string but not at 7th position.

Currently, I'm doing this in 2 steps.

First, check if 'F' is not present at position 7 and save them.

`^.{6}[^F].{7}$`

Then check if there is at least one occurrence of 'F' in the saved strings.

`^[F]+$`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If supported, you can make use of lookarounds asserting an `F` and not match it on the 7th position:

```
^(?=[^F\n]*F)(?:.{6}[^F].{7})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xAlUf/1)

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative:

```
^(?!.{6}F|[^F]+$).{14}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DFmgJk/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!.{6}F|[^F]+$)` - Negative lookahead with alternation to avoid a line with an 'F' at index 7 *or* a line with no 'F' at all;
- `.{14}$` - 14 Characters other than newline upto end-line anchor.